# I converted a bytes object into str via 'str()', how can I convert it back?

Tags: python, string, byte

I converted some Chinese characters into UTF-8 in a string object for some operations.  I now have a problem when I try to convert the string object back into a bytes object.

I tried using `bytes()`:

```
a = '一'
bytes_value = a.encode('utf-8') 
string_value = str(b)
bytes_value_again = bytes(string_value)
```

I want to convert it back to a bytes object, so I can use `decode('utf-8')` to convert it back to the original Chinese characters.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I know, the reason why I use str() is that I need the string like " b'\xe5\x8d\xa4' " for calculation ( encrypt )

Comment: No, encryption should normally be done on *bytes*, not on a string. Even if you do need to do it on a string, you want to **decode** the data. Either as UTF-8, or if a one-on-one byte-to-character mapping is needed, as Latin-1.

Comment: You do **not** want to encrypt the `'b'` character at the start, the two quote characters, or the `\xHH` escape sequences. That's a much more limited characterset, if an attacker ever guessed that you made that mistake they'd have a huge lever to crack your encryption.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thanks, that's very helpful. I am just learning cryptography and do some practice, and I know it is unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not convert `bytes` objects to strings with `str(bytes_value)`. You created a [printable representation of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

The proper way to convert from `bytes` to `str` is to *decode* the bytes to Unicode. If you have UTF-8 bytes, decode with that codec with the [`bytes.decode()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```
string_value = bytes_value.decode('utf8')
```

You *can* also specify the encoding if you want to use the `str()` function, see the  [`str(bytes_value, encoding)` form in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

```
string_value = str(bytes_value, 'utf8')
```

If you accidentally used `str(bytes_value)` and can't now get the original value by fixing that error and re-running your code, you can recover the original value by using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
bytes_representation = str(bytes_value)  # "b'....'"
recovered_bytes_value = ast.literal_eval(bytes_representation)
```

**This should only be used to recover data, not as a production-level serialisation mechanism**. `ast.literal_eval()` is quite slow, and not safe from denial-of-service attacks when used on user-supplied input (it is possible to crash Python or significantly slow it down with bad input).

If you are using an API that should really work on bytes but for some reason is only accepting strings (usually a warning sign of a incorrectly designed and implemented API), then either use a [binary-to-ASCII encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) (including [base64 / base16 / base32 / base85](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)) or decode the binary data as Latin-1.

This is even more important if you are doing this to encrypt data. The printable representation of a `bytes()` object only ever uses ASCII characters, always starts with `b'` or `b"`, and always ends in `'` or `"`. Any non-printable bytes (more than half of all 256 possible byte values) are represented with a limited range of [`\x{hh}` and `\{l}` escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). All this makes it much easier for a determined attacker to break your encryption. A best-practices encryption library will let you encrypt `bytes` directly. In fact, it is usually *preferred* to encrypt bytes.